# Automation to Read SQL Database Audit Logs in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell, automation

Is there any Automation available to Read SQL Database Audit logs in Azure.

Currently I am reading Audit Logs using the below Process, which consumes a lot of time.

1. Download the Audit Logs from Blob Storage.
2. Transfer these Audit logs into SQL Server database
3. Query SQL Server database to check the Audit Logs.

Is the any automation available to make this process simple.

Or can someone Guide me, how to make this Automated using Power shell Script or any other language.

Comment: SO rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). What have you searched for? What have you tried? Show your code. Show your error.

Comment: Hi @Baxy, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly load the logs in Azure Storage without download it.

Azure SQL Database enables you to directly load files stored on Azure Blob Storage using the [BULK INSERT T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) command and [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function.

Ref this tutorial: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-azure-sql-database/ba-p/386133

Just for now, there isn't a good way to load the Audit logs to SQL database automatically.